# AJAX request only retrieves JavaScript output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JavaScript AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: { "ajax" : "true" },
    success: function(data){
        $("#careers-content").html(data);
    }
});
```

This works great, when `ajax.php` is

```
<h3>Candidate Profile</h3>
<ul>
    <li><?php echo $role; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Then I get back

> #### Candidate profile
>
> - Some role

However if `ajax.php` is:

```
<h3>Candidate Profile</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("This file is running JavaScript!");</script>
<ul>
    <li><?php echo $role; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Then the total output I get is:

> This file is running JavaScript!

With none of the other `h3`, `ul` or `li` tags. Is there an argument that I currently can't find in jQuery's ajax function to stop this happening? How can I AJAX in the following:

> #### Candidate profile
>
> This file is running JavaScript!
>
> - Some role

i.e. import the page and javascript and run the javascript in the `ajax.php` page

Answer (score 3):

This is because `document.write` overwrites everything you have in that file, leaving the only output to `This file is running JavaScript!`

You can do something like this or similar:

```
$(document).find("h3").after("This file is running JavaScript!")
```

And you will have this output

> #### Candidate profile
>
> This file is running JavaScript!
>
> - Some role

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaNG/)